# Proper way to update code on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm worried about having to stop the server, update the code with the control version, then run

> $ rake assets:precompile

, wait, and then start the server. Users that are online when I do that will be annoyed by a broken site.

Is there a better way? Maybe a way to go into 'maintainance mode' so the users know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano) is one of the most used deployment solutions.  It allows you to set your site in maintenance mode.  I would strongly recommend using it.

If you are running more than one instance of your application, then you can update them one at a time to prevent downtime, with the exception of certain database changes.

If you **must** do this manually, (assuming your web server is set up to serve static files from the public folder) you can create an index.html file in your public directory and remove it again when you have finished the update.

Comment: index.html will only change the home page. Ok I will try capistrano, I hope it's not too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You should never interrupt the production server to deploy. Deployment should be seamless. Look into a deployment solution like [capistrano](http://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

With unicorn and Capistrano you can graceful restart your application.

```
set(:unicorn_config) {"#{current_path}/config/unicorn.rb"}
set(:unicorn_pid) {"#{current_path}/../../shared/pids/unicorn.pid"}

namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do 
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec unicorn_rails -c #{unicorn_config} -E #{rails_env} -D"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do 
    begin
      run "kill `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
    rescue
      puts "Can't kill unicorn - probably not running"
    end  
  end

  task :graceful_stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s QUIT `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end

  task :reload, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ]; then kill -USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; else cd #{deploy_to}/current && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec unicorn_rails -c #{unicorn_config} -E #{rails_env} -D; fi"
  end

end
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But I think I'm gonna stick to passenger for now